# making simple image slider for my website

Tags: html, css

guys help me figure out how the image slider works, because I've been searching for solutions but seems like nothing works. Advance thank you for helping me.

Comment: There are plenty of working examples. Start implementing a first version and post here your attempt and the errors (or weird behaviours) you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow this tutorial from W3School: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

OR there are plenty of Jquery library. You can search them in google. The one I use mostly is Slick JS: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/